# send document to a group of people:: Any one able to sign

Tags: docusignapi

We are using SOAP API with Document option. In regular way we do attach Recipient  Id to Signature Tab to send a document for Signature, in this case only one signer can do sign on Signature tab.

We need to send a Document to group of people where anyone in the group should be able to sign on it.
I have come across a concept in DocuSign call it as "Signing Group" for this we need create group manually in the DocuSign account using all required email addresses.

But as per our requirement Email addresses are not static, Email addresses are dynamic that will vary every time we do send the document.

*Signing group option is might not relevant to our requirement. Is there any other go to achieve it...?

Thanks,
Vishwa

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the current DocuSign API Documentation, it seems that the SOAP API does not support management of **signing groups** (create/delete/get/list/update) at this time.  However, the DocuSign REST API does provide that type of functionality:  https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/SigningGroups/SigningGroups/

Comment: As per our requirement "Signing group" we cant use because it needs Static Email addresses. Every time when we send document members of group will vary.

Comment: Since the REST API allows you to programmatically create Signing Groups, you can simply create a new Signing Group with the API on-the-fly for each Envelope you create/send with the API.  i.e., when it's time to programmatically create/send an Envelope, use the API to create a Signing Group that contains the appropriate members for that particular envelope, and then use that Signing Group as the recipients of that Envelope.

Comment: Yes, but as per standard DocuSign documentation we can create only 50 Signing groups for single account. If i do create Signing groups with the API, I can create and send 50 Envelops only.

Comment: Here is the Standard documentation text  ---- An account can have a maximum of 50 signing groups. Each signing group can have a maximum of 50 group members.https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/SigningGroups/SigningGroups/